# Get data from database if the input has one or more question marks.

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm tying to get inputs from a database if they have question marks on the inside.
For example:

```
GET FROM table 
WHERE input = (As long as the input as a question mark inside)
```

For example, if the input is something like, "What's your name?", it'll get it from the database. But if it only says, "What's your name.", it won't get it from the database. How do I do that?

Comment: `GET FROM table`? I've never seen that in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `like` is a bit painful because `?` is a wildcard.  One method is:

```
select t.*
from table t
where locate('?', input) > 0;
```

The alternative with `like` is to use the `escape` keyword:

```
where input like '%/?%' escape '/'
```